# iPad 2 Retina Receiving Installation Error: ApplicationVerificationFailed in Flash Builder for iOS

Tags: ios, apache-flex, air, flash-builder, ipad-mini

This is the error I'm getting when I try to install my app on my iPad Mini 2 Retina.  The application installs find on my regular old iPad 2.

[image]

**More details**:
The provisioning profile has both devices listed.  I've deleted and reinstalled the provisioning profile several times.  I shut down my Mac, my iPad, everything... I don't know what to do.

Has anyone successfully debugged on a newer iPad mini?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15081935/edit) addresses the general problem, but my app installs fine on one device, fails on another.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely sounds like a UDID issue within the provisioning profile.

I would try to add the UDID to your iOS developers account again to make sure the one you have added is correct (if it is you won't be able to add it again).

Don't manually type the UDID, copy and paste it from iTunes.

Then re-generate the provisioning profile from Apple.